Alguien sabe el por que me marca el error "com.android.volley.ClientError" cuando utilizo en la misma clase el JsonArrayRequest y RequestQueue
Pongo el codigo de JsonArrayRequest para que puedan ver el codigo que esoy utilizando en Android Studia la version 2024 En cuanto envio la peticion al servidor con la URL que necesito al parecer no va al servidor ya que inmediatamente me contesta el error "ClienteError" ya hice varias pruebas qutando todo y solo dejando un mensaje y siempre me pone este error, ya revise la URL y esta bien, solo quitando esta rutina de JsonArrayRequest me funciona  el RequestQueue
  JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL,(response) -> {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;

        for (int i=0; i < response.length() ; i++){

            try {
                JSON object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                estatus =jsonObject.getString("estatus");
                codigo_validacion1 = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("codigo_validacion"));
                if(codigo_validacion1 > 0){
                    if(!status.equals("Activo"))
                        {
                           
                            b_activar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            encabezado.setText("Captura el Codigo de Activación que te enviamos a tu CORREO");
                        }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "La Empresa ya tiene estatus de Activada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No tiene Codigo de activacion esta Empresa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Correo : " + correoE  + "Error : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de Conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    );
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

Ulilizo  tambien el RequestQueue para que puedan ver el codigo que esoy utilizando en Android Studia la version 2024
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_ACTUALIZA_ESTATUS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        res = response.substring(1, 3).trim();

                        if (res.equals("OK")){
                            Toast.makeText(ValidaCodigo.this, "Resultado: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ValidaCodigo.this, "Resultado=>: " + response , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ValidaCodigo.this, "Error--; " + error + res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                params.put("email",correoE.getText().toString());

               return params;

            }

        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        resultado = stringRequest.toString();
 

En cuanto quito el JsonArrayRequest  todo funciona, me podrian ayudar para que funcionen los dos juntos? los necesito por favor y GRACIAS
